# How do I split my emacs screen to have the echo buffer on the horizontal right?

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

In this [Tim Baldridge video (at 2.47)](https://tbaldridge.pivotshare.com/media/function-of-the-day-juxt/11920/feature) you can see he has arranged his emacs to have the echo buffer on the right of a horizontal split screen.

[image: Emacs Split screen - echo buffer on right instead of bottom]

Now when I look at the [cider shortcuts](http://www.cheatography.com/cmdrdats/cheat-sheets/my-emacs-cheat-sheet/) or even the [emacs doco](https://www.fnal.gov/docs/products/emacs/emacs/emacs_20.html) - I see nothing for this.

My question is: **How do I split my emacs screen to have the echo buffer on the horizontal right?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is [info](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Split-Window.html).

If you want to have REPL on the right side, use <kbd>C-x</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> (split vertically), then go to the right buffer (with <kbd>C-x</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, for example), and switch to the REPL via <kbd>C-x</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> or <kbd>C-x-b</kbd>.

Comment: I tried that - and it opened a REPL on the right - but my forms from the left pane were still evaluated in the echo buffer down the bottom. How can I move the echo buffer to the right? Is it possible?

Comment: @hawkeye, There is difference between REPL frame and minibuffer (bottom line where you see results of evaluation). When you evaluate expressions in left frame (your code), results will be shown in minibuffer and also in REPL. As far as I know Emacs minibuffer cannot be moved. Just open REPL with `cider-jack-in` or `C-c M-j` and locate it on the right side, then try to evaluate something from the left frame, you will see results in both REPL and minibuffer (at least warnings go into REPL for sure).

Comment: @hawkeye, Yep, results are shown only in minibuffer, however it shouldn't be a problem. I use evaluation commands mainly for evaluating of written functions. After that, I do all my testing in REPL.

Answer (score 2):

That video is not Emacs but [Intellij Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) with the [Cursive plugin](https://cursiveclojure.com). You will get that layout by default when starting or connecting to a REPL

Comment: Thanks for this - I will add I was able to reproduce this using these two links https://cursiveclojure.com/userguide/ https://cursiveclojure.com/userguide/ui.html

Comment: Glad it helped. Note that Mark's response is correct given your question, so up to you which one you prefer to accept.